# warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`. in react native

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, file-upload, digital-signature

I am new to react native. I have created a screen. in which I have added digital signature. when I dragged signature then I am saving its image in State. and then I am showing this state image on screen. but I am getting error like this = warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`. please help. here is code

```
const[Image1, setImage1]= useState(null);

    const Image1 = result.pathName;
    console.log("Response = "+Image1);
    setImage1({Image1: Image1})

 <Image
                source={{uri : Image1}}
                style={{
                 width: '100%',
                 height: 200,
                 resizeMode: 'contain',
                 }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

useState variable first word must be lower case

you cant use the same variable name,
if you're using network image then your image component should like this,

```
const[image, setImage]= useState(null);
const [imagePath,setImagePath ] = useState(result.pathName);
console.log("Response = "+imagePath);
setImage(imagePath)

 <Image 
source={{uri : image}}
style={{
width: '100%',
height: 200,
resizeMode: 'contain',
 }} 
/>
```

else if you using local image then your image component like this,

```
<Image 
source={require(image)}
style={{
width: '100%',
height: 200,
resizeMode: 'contain',
 }} 
/>
```

Comment: I am getting resonse like this =. /storage/emulated/0/saved_signature/signature.png. Is it Image . if it is Image then why its not showing on screen